# UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: Can we call this in background thread?

Tags: ios, crash, storyboard, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I'm trying to call `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` of storyboard in background thread. But I'm presenting it on main thread.

Is there good way to do so? Please give me your suggestions.

My code is something like this.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
 UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@“some” bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@“some”];
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
   });
});
```

Comment: All UI related stuff should happen in main thread so both instantiating view controller and presenting it should not occur in background thread.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please use code blocks to format code.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad idea to do *anything* to the UI on a background thread. If you're on a background thread and want to do some work on the main thread, I'd recommend [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    let vc = myStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("your-id-here")
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```